# Flask response.data raise error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

I use an online free api hoster and I have an issue with reponse.data, I use that on @app.after_request with should log path, args and server response, problem is that in console I get:

```
 GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - Error on request: Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 319, in run_wsgi execute(self.server.app) File "D:\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 308, in execute application_iter = app(environ, start_response) File "D:\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in call return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File "D:\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2084, in wsgi_app return response(environ, start_response) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

But on discord logger I see the log:

[image]

The code is :

```
def log(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        url = discord_link
        if dict(request.args) != {}:
            values = {
'username': 'Api-Logger',
'content': f'User called path:`{request.path}` with arsg: `{dict(request.args)}`'
    }
            result=external_requests.post(url, json = values)
            result.raise_for_status()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


@app.after_request
@log
def after_request_func(response):
    try:
        SECURE.send_log(str(response.data).decode("utf-8"))
        return None
    except Exception as err:
        if isinstance(err, TypeError):
            pass
        else:
            SECURE.send_log(err)
```

I don't know how to fix it But once I remove @app.after_request it works fine

Comment: Shown code doesn't match error. Please show full stacktrace

Comment: But if I remove the after_request it works fine

Comment: Okay? None of the code you've shown has the line mentioned in the error, so where does it come from?

Comment: That's the idea the flask don't show the line but once I remove after_request it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
The problem was that I was capturing the answer but not pushing further

FIXED:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request_func(response):
    SECURE.send_log((response.data).decode('utf-8'))
    return response
```